# System is unintentionally shutting down

Tags: boot, shutdown

Well, my system is turning off (shutting down), and I don't know why. It happened 4 times today. I am using the computer, and then it turns off. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more probable reason is the overheat of processor. So after the next turn off, just go to BIOS, and check temperature sensors. So after the next load of the linux check temperature of LM sensors with:

```
sensors-detect
systemctl enable lm_sensors.service
sensors
```

Or use `psensor` GUI software. Also [read the article](http://xmodulo.com/monitor-system-temperature-linux.html) on how to setup and check the temperature of the system devices.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is overheating?

You can install the program "sensors" from the terminal (type in `sensors` and it will tell you how) and check the core temperature whenever you want by typing in `sensors`

("turning off" suggests that it is shutting itself down and not just cutting out suddenly (as if the power went), which is why I am thinking overheating.. )